# Merge websites, images double ID’s issue

Tags: wordpress, image, merge, duplicates

We have multiple WordPress websites that we want to merge.
Everything works, menus, widgets, sidebars, etc.
But one thing we can't figure out and that are the images used on pages and blog items. The IDs of images are 4 digits long.
When merging the websites, we encounter the problem that an ID already exists and therefore the page shows a wrong image.

The websites combined are about 2000+ pages and 10000+ images, so it's very time consuming to replace the images manual.

Is there a way to make the IDs for example more unique by making it 20 digits?

We initially thought that Visual Composer / WPBakery was the plugin that set these IDs. But the makers of that plugin indicate that this is a WordPress core functionality.

I prefer not to adjust this.

I would like to hear if there are possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

After multiple tries, we managed to fix the issue.
For people who encounter the same issue. Here's what we did.

- Start with a 1 on 1 copy of the biggest website
- Make sure all plugins are updated and have exactly the same version numbers
- Make sure that all plugins are installed and activated (from both websites)
- Use Tools -> Export (export all)
- Use Tools -> Import, make sure Download images is ON
- Assign users and wait a while

What we did before and gave issues, was manually down and uploading the images.